# Python: match numbers from another file and return parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

with Python3.. i am trying hard to print parameter from a file "NumberMapping.txt" shown below that has a match from my CallData record field 'A_ISDN'..

'A_ISDN' field is telephony number, i get different number everytime but country prefix is going to be same.

```
CallData = 'A:QEC, B:SQ.O, Date:20181009, Duration:0, RecordClosing:480, A_ISDN:+9427159721922'
number = str(item).split('A_ISDN:')[1].split(',')[0].strip()if "A_ISDN:" in str(item) else ("")
```

by above `number` variable, i am able to extract `+942759721922` that i want to match starting numbers to the numbers in 'NumberMapping.txt'

```
cat NumberMapping.txt
+94:10001
+59:10002
+64:10003
+19:10004
+20:10005
+1:10006

expected output:
since above example has A_ISDN number started with +94, i need print/return corresponding parameter from 'NumberMapping.txt' file
10001
```

So, if `CallData` has number started with `+1`, i need to print/return corresponding parameter -- `10006`

please help and THANKS in advance.

Comment: Do the relevant `number:output` pairs have to be stored in a text file, or can they be in your program? If they can be in your program, you can use dictionaries.

Comment: is there any overlapping case? lilke might there be a mapping for +94 and also for one like +946 ?

Comment: No.. there wont be any overlapping,, because country codes are unique.

Comment: It's my fault.. i gave sample numbers.. +19:10004 & +1:10006 are actually not correct.. if have +1, i wont have any other value with overlapping like +19... Sorry for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a little bit further because I had some code already written out for a previous answer regarding how to split up a `.txt` file.

```py
# These variables would be loaded via `open`.

record_file = """A:QEC, B:SQ.O, Date:20181009, Duration:0, RecordClosing:480, A_ISDN:+9427159721922
A:BAC, B:SQ.O, Date:20281009, Duration:2, RecordClosing:523, A_ISDN:+127159721922
A:HSF, B:SQ.O, Date:28481009, Duration:5, RecordClosing:942, A_ISDN:+5959274929424
A:BAC, B:SQ.O, Date:20141009, Duration:1, RecordClosing:131, A_ISDN:+2027159721922"""
mapping_file = """+94:10001
+59:10002
+64:10003
+19:10004
+20:10005
+1:10006"""


def split_record(record):
    """ Splits the record file into a dictionary. """

    # Headers of the intended break-points in the record files.
    headers = ["A:", "B:", "Date:", "Duration:", "RecordClosing:", "A_ISDN:"]

    information = []

    # Split our record by lines.
    for line in record.split("\n"):

        # Split our record up so we only have the information per header.
        default_header = headers[0]
        for header in headers[1:]:
            line = line.replace(header, default_header)
        info = [i.strip() for i in line.split(default_header)][1:]

        # Compile our header+information together into OrderedDict's.
        compiled_information = {}
        for header, info in zip(headers, info):
            compiled_information[header[:-1]] = info

        # Append to our overall information list.
        information.append(compiled_information)

    return information


def split_mapping(mapping):
    """ Splits the phone mapping of the format +ex:num into a dictionary. """

    info = {}
    for line in mapping.split("\n"):
        split = line.split(":")
        info[split[0]] = split[1]

    return info


def record_mapping(record, mapping, number_length):
    """ Correlates the records and the mappings together. """

    info = {}
    for record in records:
        phone = record["A_ISDN"]
        extension = phone[::-1][number_length:][::-1]

        info[phone] = mappings[extension]

    return info


records = split_record(record_file)
mappings = split_mapping(mapping_file)
correlate = record_mapping(records, mappings, number_length=11)

print(correlate)
```

Outputs:

```py
{'+127159721922': '10006',
 '+2027159721922': '10005',
 '+5959274929424': '10002',
 '+9427159721922': '10001'}
```

---

### Clarification

#### `split_record()`

The first function `split_record()` takes in the *entire* record file and splits it into a dictionary. Assuming your record file is:

```
A:QEC, B:SQ.O, Date:20181009, Duration:0, RecordClosing:480, A_ISDN:+9427159721922
A:BAC, B:SQ.O, Date:20281009, Duration:2, RecordClosing:523, A_ISDN:+127159721922
A:HSF, B:SQ.O, Date:28481009, Duration:5, RecordClosing:942, A_ISDN:+5959274929424
A:BAC, B:SQ.O, Date:20141009, Duration:1, RecordClosing:131, A_ISDN:+2027159721922
```

It would output:

```
[{'A': 'QEC,',
  'A_ISDN': '+9427159721922',
  'B': 'SQ.O,',
  'Date': '20181009,',
  'Duration': '0,',
  'RecordClosing': '480,'},
 {'A': 'BAC,',
  'A_ISDN': '+127159721922',
  'B': 'SQ.O,',
  'Date': '20281009,',
  'Duration': '2,',
  'RecordClosing': '523,'},
 {'A': 'HSF,',
  'A_ISDN': '+5959274929424',
  'B': 'SQ.O,',
  'Date': '28481009,',
  'Duration': '5,',
  'RecordClosing': '942,'},
 {'A': 'BAC,',
  'A_ISDN': '+2027159721922',
  'B': 'SQ.O,',
  'Date': '20141009,',
  'Duration': '1,',
  'RecordClosing': '131,'}]
```

#### `split_mapping()`

This function simply splits the mapping file. If the mapping file is

```
+94:10001
+59:10002
+64:10003
+19:10004
+20:10005
+1:10006
```

It returns

```
{'+1': '10006',
 '+19': '10004',
 '+20': '10005',
 '+59': '10002',
 '+64': '10003',
 '+94': '10001'}
```

#### `record_mapping()`

This function correlates the record to the mapping (the two functions above). It does so by iterating through the records, extracting its phone number and its extension, and using the dictionary created for the mapping to return us the code you are looking for.

To find the extension it does so by reversing the phone number and removing 10 digits and then reversing it back again. Assuming all numbers are 10 in length (you can input it via the `number_length` variable) and extensions can be `n` amount of numbers, the function should work.

Therefore, making the output of the above functions the input for this one we have the following:

```
{'+127159721922': '10006',
 '+2027159721922': '10005',
 '+5959274929424': '10002',
 '+9427159721922': '10001'}
```

Comment: THANKS Faria.. Good learning for me & really appreciate your time and help...

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create dictionary for your mapping data and call data and then iterate over your mapping keys and if the ISDN starts with it then print the corresponding value. If you find a match break from the loop as no point checking remaining mappings

```
call_data = 'A:QEC, B:SQ.O, Date:20181009, Duration:0, RecordClosing:480, A_ISDN:+9427159721922'
number_mappings = """+94:10001
+59:10002
+64:10003
+19:10004
+20:10005
+1:10006"""

#create a dict of the call_data and mappings
call_data_dict = dict((items.split(':') for items in call_data.split(', ')))
number_mapping_dict = dict((item.split(':') for item in number_mappings.splitlines()))

#iterate over the mapping keys to see if our ISDN starts with it.
for key in number_mapping_dict:
    if call_data_dict['A_ISDN'].startswith(key):
        print(f'detected prefix {key} for msisdn {call_data_dict["A_ISDN"]} resulting value is {number_mapping_dict[key]}')
        break  # no point keep checking once we have a match
```

**OUTPUT**

```
detected prefix +94 for msisdn +9427159721922 resulting value is 10001
```